# Ionic storage not assignable number to string

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to set in ionic storage all numbers like from function below getWarrentsNumber(), but i've got an error.

Error: Argument of type "number" is not assignable to type 'string.

```
this.storage.set(this.NumberOfAssignedWarrents, 'LOCAL STORAGE BROJ');
    this.storage.get('name').then((name) => {
      console.log('Me: Hey, ' + name + '! You have a very nice name.');
      console.log('You: Thanks! I got it for my birthday.');
    });
  },
  error => {

  }
  );
```

This is a function to catch number of tasks from db:

```
getWarrentsNumber() {

    let id = localStorage.getItem('userId');

    this.peopleProvider.getAllWorkerAssignedWarrents(id).toPromise()
      .then(result => {
        this.NumberOfAssignedWarrents = result.length;
        localStorage.setItem('DodNalog', result);
      });
    this.peopleProvider.getAllWorkerFinishedWarrents(id).toPromise()
      .then(result => {
        this.NumberOfFinishedWarrents = result.length;
        localStorage.setItem('ZavNalog', result);
      });
    this.peopleProvider.getAllWorkerUnfinishedWarrents(id).toPromise()
      .then(result => {
        this.NumberOfUnfinishedWarrents = result.length;
        localStorage.setItem('NezavNalog', result);
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line throws the error, because you are setting the `key` as a number. As per ionic docs, the first parameter (`key`) should be a string.

`this.storage.set(this.NumberOfAssignedWarrents, 'LOCAL STORAGE BROJ');`

This should be changed as

`this.storage.set('LOCAL STORAGE BROJ',this.NumberOfAssignedWarrents);`